# Using Angular-Bacons $scope.$watchAsProperty(property) in Angulars ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, bacon.js

I´m trying to find a good way to use Baconjs together with Angularjs in conjuctions with Angular-Bacon.

Now digesting from Bacon to the Angular scope works perfectly fine but I´m stumbling with Angular-Bacons $scope.$watchAsProperty(property) within Angulars ng-repeat:

Let´s say I have the Angular scope $scope.databaserecords and render it out with:

```
<div ng-repeat="record in databaserecords">
```

Each of the records has a record.checked property and I want to handle all checked records together in one Bacon stream, for example to add a certain tag to all records at once.

At this point using $scope.$watchAsProperty(databaserecords) I get no Bacon events when checking or unchecking certain records, so how could I accomplish to receive these changes back in Bacon?

I might also mention, that using $scope.$watchAsProperty(property) out of ng-repeat, for example for input fields, works well without any problem.

Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, your actual *databaserecords* remains the same throughout the scope, so you'll need to invoke *$watchAsProperty* with the [objectEquality](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch) argument set to true:

```
$scope.$watchAsProperty("databaserecords", true)
```

By default angular opts to compare objects with a simple object equality check. In your case the list object remains the same, so a deeper check is necessary. This is already implemented in angular-bacon but it seems I've omitted it from the docs.